# HTTPS - ssl error bad cert domain

Tags: tls

When I try to visit some websites with HTTPS , I get the error that the
SSL is self-signed and that the SSL is only valid for another domain, and that SSL is actually invalid.
If the SSL is valid only for other domains(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain) what should I do?
 Stay to Http or go Https. Also can you explain my what is actually happening when I get that error.

Also when a certificate is only self-singed (Error code: sec_error_untrusted_issuer), I prefer HTTPS over HTTP, is what am I doing better?

Answer (score 3):

The SSL server certificate is meant to convey the *public key* of the server. This is the method by which you can know that you are talking to the right server, not a fake one setup by some attacker intent on grabbing your password or credit card details. If you browser warns you about the certificate, then this guarantee has evaporated (like dew in the morning Sun, as the usual metaphor goes).

The **sane** reaction when faced with a certificate-based warning from the browser is to stop accessing the site altogether. Proceeding with HTTP or HTTPS on that site is at your own risks.

If you MUST really browse that site, then just consider it as unreliable and unprotected. You don't really know if you are using the genuine server, or a fake one. Don't send any sensitive information to that server. Don't consider that any information sent by that server is true.

(In that situation, HTTPS is still "better" than HTTP in the following sense: if the error is due not to an actual attack, but a thorough misconfiguration, then HTTPS will still do some SSL which will offer some protection against *passive* attackers, who spy on the line but don't try to interfere with data exchanges. This is not a big protection, because passive-only attackers are rare.)

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed certificate means that it is not issued by trusted Certificate Authority. 
Imagine your credit card being issued by yourself, not by your bank. Would sales assistant  trust it?

In this case the webserver owner has to reconfigure. And you as a user can decide whether to trust this website and go on HTTP or leave.